# path to background-image in css with specific base href in Angular 9

Tags: css, angular

The baseHref param in angular.json is /iofrog/ + there are 7 languages defined in i18n.locales, so the final baseHref in index.html is /iofrog/en for English build.

in css file for app component I have:

```
background-image: url('~/assets/img/background.jpg');
```

This is translated by Angular 9 CLI to path /iofrog/assets/img/background.jpg, so /en/ is skipped! Is it a bug in Angular CLI?

I also tried:

```
background-image: url('/assets/img/background.jpg');  // not showing the image
background-image: url('./assets/img/background.jpg'); // compiler error
background-image: url('assets/img/background.jpg');  // not showing the image
```

I also found --rebaseRootRelativeCssUrls=true|false option but it is depreciated.

The workaround that is working is in TS:

```
this.backgroundImageURL = `url(${this.baseHref}assets/img/background.jpg)`;
```

And in HTML template:

```
[style.background-image]="backgroundImageURL ? backgroundImageURL : ''"
```

But this is not elegant and the image is loading after the html is rendered.

What is the correct solution in Angular 9?

Answer (score 12):

There were some issues with i18n building angular app and base href.

It should work with that syntax for scss files:

```
background-image: url('~src/assets/img/background.jpg');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This copies the asset files in the root folder for some reason so they get deployed twice

Comment: I almost gave up trying to figure this out. Thank you sir 

Answer (score 0):

Works for me in package.json add this to your command

```
--base-href ../ --deploy-url ../
```

or

```
--base-href ' ' --deploy-url ' '
```

CSS if loads an asset:

```
background-image: url('/assets/graphics/image.svg')
```

on index.html 1st line as `<base href="/">`

Double-check in angular.json - "projects"

```
  "root": "",
  "sourceRoot": "src",
  "projectType": "application",
  "prefix": "app",
```

Comment: however, this is not a perfect solution